# Which SciFi movie is this quote from?

Tags: story-identification, quotes

> "Science ain't exact science with these clowns."

I was told on SFF chat that it's a quote from SciFi movie.

But [Google Search shows zip](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Science+ain%27t+exact+science+with+these+clowns%22&oq=%22Science+ain%27t+exact+science+with+these+clowns%22&gs_l=hp.3...417.5960.0.6152.4.4.0.0.0.0.110.346.2j2.4.0.les;..0.0...1c.1j2.-rOd8slMjs4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a542392d10e4b1d3&biw=1280&bih=939) - one site that isn't even in English. (probably the exact quote wording differs?)

Which SciFi movie is this quote from?

---

**UPDATE**: Moral - don't search for in-exact quotes by encapsulating your search string in quotes.

Comment: Downvoter care to offer an explanation?

Comment: @DVK try the search without the `"` (quotes) and then you get results.

Comment: @DVK: [try this](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Science+ain%27t+exact+science+with+these+clowns&oq=Science+ain%27t+exact+science+with+these+clowns&gs_l=hp.3...3379.3379.1.3742.1.1.0.0.0.0.57.57.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.H4rV2wkcJQ4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=bf525e541b623bda&biw=1366&bih=667). Currently this question is in fourth place.

Comment: [This is the third link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114746/quotes) on Google when I searched without quotes.

Comment: Meh. Too used to the fact that usually you HAVE to quote when searching for quotes. Voting to close as general reference since quote-less search points to IMDB that is considered GR

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Twelve Monkeys](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114746/quotes)*

> **Louie:** Science ain't an exact science with these clowns but, they're getting better.